# Why are my changes not being reflected in css? Django bootstrap

Tags: css, django

So I am noticing that my css changes are not being reflected. I did a hard-reload and cleared the cache but still nothing. Like I can literally delete the css file and my badge which I'm trying to edit is still there... it only goes away once I take it off of base.html directly. So what is going on here? I have a static folder in my app, with a css folder and then my css/notification file. I tried doing `collectstatic` through terminal but that doesn't do anything.

**settings.py/static **

```
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = [
"/DatingAppCustom/dating_app/static",
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'dating_app/media')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't loaded the staick files to the html template,
{% load static %}